# Did the Symfony validation rules change with the update?

Tags: php, symfony, validation

After updating from Symfony 2.x to Symfony 4.x and checking the operation, there was a change in the validation rule of the email address.
In Symfony 2.x, non-alphanumeric words like "あ@test.co.jp" were repelled by Symfony validation, but not in Symfony 4.x. Did the rules change with the update?
Also, is there a way to undo the rules?
With my own validation rules, I'm afraid that the email address I used to use may get caught in the validation.
Also, if you remove the "@", you will get a validation error message "Not a valid email address", so it is considered that the validation itself is working.

Validation specification code common to Symfony 2.x and Symfony 4.x

```yaml
        Mail:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Email: ~
```

Comment: `あ@test.co.jp` is [a valid email address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email).

Comment: @yivi I see, the rules have changed internationally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically 2.1 just validated your mail with no option as to how.

[2.5](https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/reference/constraints/Email.html#strict) introduced `strict` mode - [here is the commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/3368630482c0f5f5c0ebaf08e64347ae68e3e733).

As you can see, before this change Symfony would use `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`. After the change it used [EmailValidator](https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator) for strict mode.

[4.1](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/reference/constraints/Email.html#mode) then [replaced that](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-html5-email-validation) with the `mode` option for more granularity.

> Validation of email addresses is one of those never-ending debates among developers. Some argue that you can't truly validate them programmatically and that you must always send a confirmation email. Others argue that RFC 5322 compliant programmatic validation is enough for real-world applications.

> Symfony always made this choice yours with the strict option of the Email validation constraint. When false, the email address is validated against a simple regular expression. If true, a RFC compliant validation is done using the egulias/email-validator third-party library.

> However, the regular expression used to validate email addresses was too simple. That's why in Symfony 4.1 we decided to start using the same email validation done by HTML5. In practice, we've deprecated the strict option in favor of a new mode option

I would assume that there are some differences between strict mode and the pre 2.5 method of using `filter_var`.

If you need to preserve the exact functionality I think you need to add a [custom constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/validation/custom_constraint.html) that uses `filter_var` - something like this:

```
# src/Validator/FilterVarEmail.php
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class FilterVarEmail extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Email invalid.';
}

# src/Validator/FilterVarEmailValidator.php
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class FilterVarEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        /* @var $constraint \App\Validator\FilterVarEmail */

        if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
            return;
        }

        if (false === filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation()
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** That said, it is worth noting that special characters are allowed in email addresses as well as domain names so really to future-proof your system you probably want to change it to support this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
After all there was a change. Is it a recognition that strict should be set to true to make it similar to 2.3?

Comment: @scottie320 no, that's not the same unfortunately. I updated my answer with some more info for you.

Comment: Thank you. I understood it well.
Custom validation also worked and was what I was looking for.